# planar graphs of size $n \geq 2$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm given the problem: Let G be a planar graph of order $n \geq 2$. Prove that G has at least two vertices whose degrees are at most 5.

I know, based on Euler's Formula, that $e \leq 3n - 6$ and that for every planar graph, there is a vertex whose degree is at most 5. I also know that $d_1 + d_2 + .. + d_n = 2e$ where $d_i$ is the degree of vertex i but outside of that, I'm not really sure where to go from here. This is a homework problem, so any **hints** would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use 
$$d_1+d_2+..+d_n=2e \leq 6n-12$$
and contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, the claim is true when $n=2$, now assume $n \geq 3$.

If a counterexample exists, it has at least $n-1$ vertices of degree $6$ or more.  It follows that $$d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_n \geq 6(n-1).$$  This contradicts [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula), which implies $$d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_n = 2e \leq 6(n-2)$$ since $n \geq 3$.